# How to upgrade neo4j from 2.2.9 to 3.4.0?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I want to upgrade from 2.2.9 to 3.4.0. I have seen both .extension are different.V2.2.9 .graphdb but V3.4.0 .db also i'm getting error.

Is there an option available to upgrade to 3.4.0? Please advise.

```
    2018-08-14 19:11:15.489+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@59a67c3a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store version 'v0.A.5'". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@59a67c3a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store version 'v0.A.5'".
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@59a67c3a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store version 'v0.A.5'".
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntryPoint.java:22)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@59a67c3a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store version 'v0.A.5'".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, C:\Users\manickamv\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-10ce8a02-4af1-41bf-940c-b7ef6f48046f\installation-3.4.1\data\databases\graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:212)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.enterprise.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.<init>(EnterpriseGraphDatabase.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@2de366bb' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store version 'v0.A.5'".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:208)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown store version 'v0.A.5'
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.format.RecordFormatSelector.selectForVersion(RecordFormatSelector.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.java:211)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.<init>(NeoStores.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:160)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openAllNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.<init>(RecordStorageEngine.java:200)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.buildStorageEngine(NeoStoreDataSource.java:574)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade in steps, Neo4j recommends you upgrade to the most up to date version of the current minor version, in your case, I would try upgrading to `2.3.12`, then going to `3.2.12`, then `3.4.5` - it's mainly as there have been a lot of changes since `2.2.x` which need to be done in steps.

Comment: Okay, but where to download older versions of neo4j? like V2.3.12..I have searched good but i couldn't find archive versions page from neo4j site. Please advise

Comment: Err, the same place you downloaded 3.4.0 from? https://neo4j.com/download-center/